# How to display ListPart items of Orchard Core CMS in razor view?

Tags: list, razor, orchardcms, display

I have created a content type projects, which is a list of project in Orchard CMS. When I try to display this list in razor view, the ListPart has no items.

Projects:

[image: Projects]

project:

[image: project]

Answer (score 2):

you can get ListPart items using this method
@Orchard.QueryListItemsAsync(Model.ContentItemId)

of course, you have to do this injection first
@inject OrchardCore.IOrchardHelper Orchard

Comment: There are two new helpers and filters to list the items of a List Part. The two news Orchard helpers are:

QueryListItemsAsync: returns the enumerable of list items satisfying given predicate.
QueryListItemsCountAsync: returns the number of list items satisfying given predicate.

Comment: Curious if this will work to display one list in various ways. For example, let's say you have a List for Invoices (Listable Metadata), with an Invoice Content Item. Simple enough. But what if you have Clients as Users, and now you want to filter the List to either show a) All Invoices (simple enough), and b) Invoices for Client "x"? Can this help to do that?